# NodeJS express serve static page, then throw 404 error

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running an app with Node.js and Express. I created the skeleton of the project with Express Generator. Here is a section of the generated code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Create routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/data', dataRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// Catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// Error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  console.log ('ERROR :', err.status);
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

When a static page is served, It continues and generates a 404 error. In the browser everything is fine, but in the Node.js logs, I can see the `console.log('ERROR`). Why the engine does not stop when a static page is served? How to solve it?

Comment: see the [fallthrough option](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#fallthrough) by default its `true`, so it will `next()` without the error `next(err)`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone When I set `fallthrough` to false the routes are no longer working.